# Can't cancel htaccess changes

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I tried to add a 301 redirect to my website, so i added a few lines to the htaccess file in the /www/ folder. Now domain.com is always redirected to domain.com/www/ (which doesn't work), eventhough i removed those lines from the htaccess file.

Here is the code i used and recanted:

```
Options -Indexes
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

How can i cancel these changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser probably still has those redirects cached because it was a 301 (permanent) redirect. Try restarting your browser.

Comment: wow. You're right, things work as they should on chrome. But i can't get firefox to "forget" those redirects by restarting it. How do i make it ?

Comment: @Splint You'll need to do a little bit of research depending on the version, but [here's a good place to start](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=make+firefox+forget+301+redirect&oq=how+to+make+firefox+forget+301&gs_l=serp.1.0.0i22i30l2.477892.483191.0.485349.34.23.0.11.11.0.157.2042.19j4.23.0...0.0...1c.1.9.serp.OqTGJmrrlhk)

Comment: about:config, Toggled browser.cache.disk.enable off then back on. That did the trick. Thank you my good sir.